# Как сократить метод:=?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Пишу код, формирования csv файла из properties. Но по тз преподавателя метод должен быть не более 15 строк, поэтому вопрос, можно ли как то его сократить, например, заменить цикл на лямбда-выражение (не особо в этом разбираюсь, так как только в процессе изучения)

```
public void createAnswerFail() throws CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException, IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException {
        log.info("insertAnswerFail");
        File fileAnswer = new File(Constants.ANSWER_PROPERTIES_CONST);
        Properties propertiesAnswer = new Properties();
        propertiesAnswer.load(new FileReader(fileAnswer));
        List<Answer> answerList = new ArrayList<>();
        DataProviderCSV instance = new DataProviderCSV();
        int k=1;
        for (int i=1; i<=2; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
                Answer answer;
                answer = createAnswer(k, propertiesAnswer.getProperty(Constants.ANSWER_CONST + i + "_" + j) , Integer.parseInt(propertiesAnswer.getProperty(Constants.WEIGHT_CONST+j)));
                answerList.add(answer);
                k++;

            }
        }
        instance.createAnswer(answerList);
        assertNull((instance.getAnswerById(9)));
    }
```

Comment: разделите на 2 метода?

Comment: `Answer answer = createAnswer(k, ...` вот уже -1 строка. Строку с `k++;` засунуть в второй цикл рядом с `j++` и еще -1 строка

Answer (score 0):

```
public void createAnswerFail() throws CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException, IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException {
            log.info("insertAnswerFail");
            Properties propertiesAnswer = new Properties().load(new FileReader(new File(Constants.ANSWER_PROPERTIES_CONST)));
            // Данная строка может работать некорректно, однако если вернуть все в изначальный вид, то в норматив все равно уложится.
            List<Answer> answerList = new ArrayList<>();
            DataProviderCSV instance = new DataProviderCSV();
            for (int i=1, k=1; i<=2; ++i) for (int j = 1; j <= 4; ++j, ++k) answerList.add(createAnswer(k, propertiesAnswer.getProperty(Constants.ANSWER_CONST + i + "_" + j) , Integer.parseInt(propertiesAnswer.getProperty(Constants.WEIGHT_CONST+j))));
            instance.createAnswer(answerList);
            assertNull((instance.getAnswerById(9)));
        }
```

Очевидно, что написанное выше является примером плохого кода и так делать не надо. Первоначальный код куда понятнее и читабельнее.